# react-query: Query is always fetching

Tags: reactjs, typescript, caching, react-query

I'm new to the react-query library and I faced a weird situation that I don't understand.
I have a query that gets the authenticated user from the server

```
const me = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get<MeResponse>(`/auth/me`, {
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  return data.user;
};

const meQuery = useQuery("auth", me);
```

AuthContext provides this query to the rest of my app:

```
export const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        me: meQuery,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

it's always fetching!

[image]

I tried to manually invalidate the query using `invalidateQueries('auth')` and `clear` functions but after invalidation, react-query doesn't try to re-fetch data and the server doesn't receive any request.

Apparently, the data is cached by react-query even when I set cacheTime and staleTime to 0.

I don't understand this behavior. Maybe it's a bug in devtools. Can you explain it to me?

**EDIT:** I think I found the problem. when I solved it I will write the answer (read the comments)

Comment: let us know what the problem is once you identified it. As a remark, I would suggest to _not_ put data from react-query into context. I think there is no real need to do that. If you need data available anywhere in your component tree, you can just call `useMeQuery()` again. react-query makes your data available throughout the application - it is not only a caching library, but also a "global state management library" for server state.

Comment: Thank for the advice. I'm new to react-query and I'm still in the previous world. but it makes sense. The problem was that I haven't handled response errors properly so the query was never completed and that caused this wired behavior. The only thing that I've done was to add a try/catch block in the "me" function and handle the error:)

Comment: I see you are destructuring data from the `axios.get` response. This is known to cause the issue that you are experiencing because of the scope variable name clashing when you use the `data` property that useQuery returns. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75868820/11735399