# react-query returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using react 18.2 with redux toolkit and react-query.

I set up my code as follow, but I got **data return in react-query** as **undefined**. 
However, I do get the response when inspecting the network tab in chrome browser.
First time implementing react-query. What am I doing wrong?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import persistStore from 'redux-persist/es/persistStore';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import store from './redux/store';
import './i18n';

const persistor = persistStore(store);

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <App />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import { useQuery} from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('repoData', async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query');
        return data;
    });

    if (isLoading) {
        return <>Loading</>
    }


    if (error) {
        return <>Error</>
    }
    console.log(data);
    return (
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Perhaps you can `console.log` the data returned from the API inside of the function that you're passing to `useQuery` to make sure that you're getting the response you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

instead of this code

```
const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query');
return data;
```

use this way

```
const data  = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query');
return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fix:

You need to rename the `data` variable that you extract from your query:

```
const { isLoading, error, data: repoData } = useQuery(['repoData'], fetchData);
```

Note that I have extracted your function passed to the query in a `fetchData` but it remains unchanged. You can name your variable as you wish.

It's a scope issue related to the variable naming. In your code, you are destructuring both the Axios response and the React Query response with the same variable name, data. This seems to make the variables clash.

#### Tip:

I'd like to suggest you use `@tanstack/react-query` as it is recommended.  Mind that if you do the query key is then passed as an array so you will need to modify your query like so:

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(['repoData'], async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query');
  return response.data;
});
```

I also recommend using the react query dev tools. This will help you further debug problems. In your `index.js` add this line:

```
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'
```

And then place this line in your QueryClientProvider component:

```
 <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
```

It will look like this:

```
<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  <App />
  <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
</QueryClientProvider>
```